# Playframework standalone jobs connect to database twice

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a standalone job in Play 2.0.4 that I want to run on Heroku as described in https://github.com/jamesward/play2-scheduled-job-demo
I start the application just like in the samples:

```
public class QueueWorker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application application = new Application(new File(args[0]), QueueWorker.class.getClassLoader(), null, Mode.Dev());
        Play.start(application);
    }
}
```

But now, judging from the logs, Play connects to the database *twice* for some reason and EhCache fails the second time because it the name is already registered:

```
[[37minfo[0m] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://localhost/myproject?characterEncoding=UTF-8
[[37minfo[0m] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://localhost/myproject?characterEncoding=UTF-8
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.ehcache.ObjectExistsException: Cache play already exists
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addCache(CacheManager.java:990)
    at play.api.cache.EhCachePlugin.x$3(Cache.scala:111)
    at play.api.cache.EhCachePlugin.cache(Cache.scala:109)
    at play.api.cache.EhCachePlugin.onStart(Cache.scala:127)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:60)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
    at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:60)
    at play.api.Play.start(Play.scala)
    at jobs.QueueWorker.main(QueueWorker.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Interestingly this does not happen when I start the project with the "play run" command. Has anybody got a hint for me what this could be, or how I can debug where it's coming from?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm launching the QueueWorker from within IntelliJ with just the "." as a parameter and not on Heroku. Therefor I don't think the Procfile has anything to do with it.

Comment: ah ok. Did you create a Global.onStart() method ? And I also notice in the code provided that you use `Mode.Dev()` for your application, but you may try with `Mode.Prod()`.

Comment: Yes I have Global.onStart() implemented. If I comment it out, I get the error nevertheless. Switching to Mode.Prod() didn't change anything as well.

Comment: I just made a test with a 2.0.3 app, I don't have the issue. Are you using some other plugins or modules ?

Comment: The sample from play2-scheduled-job-demo works fine with my 2.0.4 installation as well. I'm at a loss to explain what's going on with my app. I use the Guice and play-authenticate modules, but if I throw them all out of the play.plugins it doesn't change anything either.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the problem lies with the play-authenticate module. Even if you remove all entries from play.plugins and just let it sit in your dependencies, it will generate this kind of error. I created an error report at https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/issues/23 and hope it will be fixed soon.